# Compiler error using global variables 'extern' in header files in C++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, java-native-interface, global-variables, extern

I'm using the Java Native Interface and trying to make the JNIEnv environment pointer (*env) a global variable. I'm using eclipse with g++ and I have the following files:

CustomLibrary.hh

```
#ifndef CUSTOMLIBRARY_HH_
#define CUSTOMLIBRARY_HH_

#include <jni.h>
extern JNIEnv *env;

#endif /* CUSTOMLIBRARY_HH_
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include "CustomLibrary.hh"

int main()
{
    //create java virtual machine

   JavaVM *javaVM = nullptr; 
   JNIEnv *env = nullptr;
   long flag = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&javaVM, (void**)&env, &vmArgs);

   if (flag == JNI_ERR)

   //call some other class method which uses the env global variable
   myclass MYCLASS();
   MYCLASS::doSomething();
}
```

myclass.cpp

```
#include "CustomLibrary.hh"

myclass::doSomething()
{
    anotherFunction(env);    
}
```

However, whenever I try to build the project I get the following error:

```
myclass.cpp: undefined reference to 'env'
```

I'm not entirely sure what the problem is.

Comment: You need a  global variable definition of `env` to match your declaration. Your `myclass MYCLASS();` won't do what you expect it to do, and `myclass MYCLASS::doSomething();` is not valid. I strongly recommend you read a C++ book if you are planning to program this language.

Comment: Oops meant to put MYCLASS::doSomething()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is one of scope.

```
extern JNIEnv *env;
```

is in the global scope.  That means it is a different variable from

```
JNIEnv *env = nullptr;
```

that you declare in `main`, since it is scoped to `main`.  You need to put

```
JNIEnv *env = nullptr;
```

in the global space of a single cpp file in order for it to be defined.

Comment: OP has other issues in the snippet as well.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, it makes sense but I have now moved the `JNIEnv *env = nullptr;` line out of the main() function to the top of the file. However I am still getting the same compilation error

Comment: @kahamster How are you compiling the files?  You need to link them all together in order for it to work.

Comment: Oh stupid me...I forgot to update my makefile with the CustomLibrary.hh file xD Thank you Nathan!

Comment: @kahamster No problem.  Glad to help.